# get all 3 digit number whose sum is 11 or we can say module is 1 in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

In response I want all 3 digit numbers whose sum is 11 and also gives module 1 and
also want to know how can I push 000 in array in js.

For example number = 128, sum = 11 and module(remainder) = 1.
Like this I want all that numbers in array.
Can anyone share the logic for the same.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to try that yourself first.

Comment: In what way do you get modulo one?

Comment: You mean `1%2%8`...?

Comment: the sum of that digit must be 11, as above example 1+2+8=11, and 11%10=1.

Comment: `11%10` is always `1` so what is the need for that check ?

Comment: Where does the "11%10" come from in this case? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the second check is supposed to be (the modulus of something has to be `1`). If that is supposed to be that the modulus of all digits of the number has to be `1`, here is how you could do it:

```js
var results = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
      if (i + j + k === 11 && i % j % k === 1) {
        results.push(i.toString() + j.toString() + k.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

OR:

```js
var results = [];
for (let i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
  const [one, two, three] = i.toString().split('').map(i => +i);
  if (one + two + three === 11 && one % two % three === 1) {
    results.push(i.toString());
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Basically just go through all the possible combination and do the checks on each number.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a brute force approach and check the sum with eleven. A check with the remainder is not necessary, because `11` has always a rest of one, if divided by ten.

```js
const
    getSum = v => [...v.toString()].reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0),
    values = [];


for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (getSum(i) === 11) values.push(i);
}

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think you need to start the loop at `100` because it says *all 3 digit numbers*

Comment: not like,this,as I mention sum of that digit must be 11, as above example 1+2+8=11, and 11%10=1.

Comment: @Nileshsolanki, why the remainder of one?

Comment: @NinaScholz want to implement that thing in one of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var arr=[1,128,15];
var remainder = 127;
var result = arr.filter(function(i) {
  var str=i.toString().split('');
  var sum=0;
  str.forEach(function(c) { return sum+=Number(c); });
  return sum===11 && (i%remainder)===1;
});
```

and more fancy and ES6:

```
const arr=[1,128,15];
const remainder = 127;
const result = arr.filter(i=>{
  const sum=i.toString().split('').reduce((s,v)=>(+v)+s,0);
  return sum===11 && (i%remainder)===1;
});
```